# Parse json key value from inside of a json object

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
   "data":
      {
         "key1" : "Key"
      }
}
```

I am currently trying to parse the value of the key named, 'key1' from inside of the jso object, I am still quite new to javascript and am unsure as to how i would achieve this.

The JSON is located inside of a file named, 'jsonData.json'

Comment: When you say automatically what do you mean?

Comment: where is that json data coming from? Is it in a variable? an external .json file?

Comment: it is in a JSON file @Always Learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ‘require’ the file then access the value like this:

```
const theData = require(‘./filename.json’);
const value = theData.data.key1;
```

What is happening is the `require` loads the file and converts it to a JavaScript object. That object gets assigned to the local variable `theData`, which you can then use to navigate the contents of the object with.

Answer (score 0):

if it is an object constructed like this it wouldn't it be

`let theVal = data.key1;`